# Plotting distance arrows in technical drawing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to indicate a distance in one of my plots. What I have in mind is the way they do it in technical drawings, showing a double headed arrow with the distance as text beside it.

**Example:**

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

hlines(7,0,2, linestyles='dashed')
hlines(11,0,2, linestyles='dashed')
hlines(10,0,2, linestyles='dashed')
hlines(8,0,2, linestyles='dashed')
plot((1,1),(8,10), 'k',) # arrow line
plot((1,1),(8,8), 'k', marker='v',) # lower arrowhead
plot((1,1),(10,10), 'k', marker='^',) # upper arrowhead
text(1.1,9,"D=1")
```

This results in something like this (two of the hlines are not really needed, they just increase the drawing area...): [image: Distance marker manual style]

Is there a quicker way to do this, preferably with arrowheads which end on the exact spot, not below/above where they should be?
Extra points for placing the text automatically as well.

**Edit:**
I had been playing with `annotate` but since the string would have to be sacrificed this solution had lost some appeal to me. Thanks for pointing out the arrowstyle though, it wasn't working when I attempted something similar.
I guess there is no way around writing a little function to do it with one call...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hlines(7, 0, 2, linestyles='dashed')
plt.hlines(11, 0, 2, linestyles='dashed')
plt.hlines(10, 0, 2, linestyles='dashed')
plt.hlines(8, 0, 2, linestyles='dashed')
plt.annotate(
    '', xy=(1, 10), xycoords='data',
    xytext=(1, 8), textcoords='data',
    arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '<->'})
plt.annotate(
    'D = 1', xy=(1, 9), xycoords='data',
    xytext=(5, 0), textcoords='offset points')

# alternatively,
# plt.text(1.01, 9, 'D = 1')

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

For more information on the many options available with `plt.annotate`, see [this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).

---

As shown above, the text can be placed with either `plt.annotate` or `plt.text`. With `plt.annotate` you can specify the offset (e.g. `(5, 0)`) in points, whereas with `plt.text` you can specify the text location in data coordinates (e.g. `(1.01, 9)`).

Comment: you can use data coords with `annotate` too.

Comment: Right, but I think in this case uses `offset points` is more useful since it will prevent the label from drifting/stretching away from the arrow if the figure is expanded.

Comment: how would you adjust the size of the arrow?

Comment: @dbliss: [Per the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) when you specify `arrowstyle` you get a `FancyArrowPatch` which offers a choice from a fixed set of styles which do not allow customization of the arrow, AFAIK. However, if you remove `arrowstyle='<->'`, then you get a `YAArrow`  which allows you to set `width`, `frac`, `headwidth` arrowprops key/values.

Comment: In your example you can see a small gap between the tips of the arrowheads and the dashed lines - in some cases this gap looks annoyingly imprecise. Do you happen to know of a way to position the tips of the arrowheads so that they are exactly touching the point(s) that they are supposed to be labelling?

Comment: @ali_m: include `{'shrinkA':0, 'shrinkB':0}` to `arrowprops`. This removes the default 2 points used to shrink the arrows.

Answer (score 13):

Try using `annotate`:

```
annotate ('', (0.4, 0.2), (0.4, 0.8), arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<->'})
```

[image: Image produced by annotate command]

I'm not sure about automatic text placement though.

Answer (score 2):

I've crafted a function that accomplishes this nicely:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def annotate_point_pair(ax, text, xy_start, xy_end, xycoords='data', text_offset=6, arrowprops = None):
    """
    Annotates two points by connecting them with an arrow. 
    The annotation text is placed near the center of the arrow.
    """

    if arrowprops is None:
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle= '<->')

    assert isinstance(text,str)

    xy_text = ((xy_start[0] + xy_end[0])/2. , (xy_start[1] + xy_end[1])/2.)
    arrow_vector = xy_end[0]-xy_start[0] + (xy_end[1] - xy_start[1]) * 1j
    arrow_angle = np.angle(arrow_vector)
    text_angle = arrow_angle - 0.5*np.pi

    ax.annotate(
            '', xy=xy_end, xycoords=xycoords,
            xytext=xy_start, textcoords=xycoords,
            arrowprops=arrowprops)

    label = ax.annotate(
        text, 
        xy=xy_text, 
        xycoords=xycoords,
        xytext=(text_offset * np.cos(text_angle), text_offset * np.sin(text_angle)), 
        textcoords='offset points')

    return label
```