# Annotating dimensions in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to annotate certain lengths in a matplotlib figure. For example, the distance between points A and B.

For this, I think I can either use [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) and figure out how to supply the start and end positions of the arrow. Or, use [arrow](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow) and label the point.

I tried to use the latter, but I can't figure out how to get a 2-headed arrow:

```
from pylab import *

for i in [0, 1]:
    for j in [0, 1]:
        plot(i, j, 'rx')

axis([-1, 2, -1, 2]) 
arrow(0.1, 0, 0, 1, length_includes_head=True, head_width=.03) # Draws a 1-headed arrow
show()
```

How do I create a 2-headed arrow? Better still, is there another (simpler) way of marking dimensions in matplotlib figures?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting distance arrows in technical drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612637/plotting-distance-arrows-in-technical-drawing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the style of an arrow by using the `arrowstyle` property, for example

```
ax.annotate(..., arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->'))
```

gives a double headed arrow.

A complete example can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html) about a third the way down the page with the possible different styles.

As for a 'better' way of marking dimensions on plots I cannot think of any off the top of my head.

Edit: here's a complete example you can use if it's helpful

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def annotate_dim(ax,xyfrom,xyto,text=None):

    if text is None:
        text = str(np.sqrt( (xyfrom[0]-xyto[0])**2 + (xyfrom[1]-xyto[1])**2 ))

    ax.annotate("",xyfrom,xyto,arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->'))
    ax.text((xyto[0]+xyfrom[0])/2,(xyto[1]+xyfrom[1])/2,text,fontsize=16)

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
annotate_dim(plt.gca(),[0,0],[np.pi,0],'$\pi$')

plt.show()
```

Comment: But for annotate, how do I control exactly where the arrow begins and ends?

Comment: using the properties `xy` and `xytext` (both tuples of length 2). `annotate` assumes you want to add some text, if you do not simply pass an empty string as the first argument.

Comment: So just to be clear on this: if you want a dimension line, where the text is centered and "slightly above" the dimension line - you cannot use the text in the annotate call itself, as it will snap to one endpoint - and that is why we must add the arrow and the text separately, correct? I also tried to use the `va="center", ha="center"` attributes - but the text still snaps to one endpoint...

Answer (score 2):

The following gives a nice dimension in your plot: The annotation is added twice with different arrowprops ('<->' and '|-|') after which a text is put centered on the middle of the line and a bbox is used to cover the line under the label.

```
axs[0].annotate("", xy=(0, ht), xytext=(w, ht), textcoords=axs[0].transData, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->'))
axs[0].annotate("", xy=(0, ht), xytext=(w, ht), textcoords=axs[0].transData, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='|-|'))
bbox=dict(fc="white", ec="none")
axs[0].text(w/2, ht, "L=200 m", ha="center", va="center", bbox=bbox)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had a much shorter span to annotate, so I added the following to the `arrowprops` dict: `shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0, color='k'` (for some reason my default color was white). I also adjusted the padding around the text by adding `boxstyle="square,pad=0.1"` to the `bbox` dict.